# Contacts not syncing to icloud

Tags: iphone, icloud, data-synchronization, contacts

I've realised that all new contacts added since replacing my iPhone over a year ago have been going to the wrong account (a non i-cloud one) and therefore not syncing.

There are 203 and so it will take hours to manually recreate each one and delete old one.  Any clever ideas to move them over?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is an amazing app that backs your contacts up in a .vsf file. You can then email or text yourself the contacts for later use or backup. Here is the link:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-contacts-backup/id446784593?mt=8

I'm not affiliated in any way with this app.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a mac, you can use a usb cable to do a 1-time wired sync with iTunes, which will allow you to merge your contacts to your Mac's address book.  Make sure your Mac is also syncing with iCloud (System Preferences -> iCloud) and the addresses will go to the right place.

Then be sure to remove the old/incorrect account from your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, in my opinion, is to open the Contacts app on your Mac and do a **drag-and-drop** of all those contacts into your iCloud account.

This assumes the following:

1. You have a Mac
2. The email account (non-iCloud) is setup on the Mac, **and** with contact syncing enabled.

If so, just open the Contacts app on your Mac, and select the **non-iCloud** account (not "All Contacts") on the far left hand side. You will then see all those 203 contacts. Select them all and drag-and-drop to iCloud. Done.